# How do I change NA to 0 with lapply()?

Tags: r

I have a list of datasets.

```
dfList <- list(df1,df2,df3)
```

Each dataset looks like this.

```
apples, oranges
1,      2
NA,     4
```

I want to programatically change each dataframe's `NA`s to `0`s. How do I do this?

My code so far...

```
lapply(
  X = dfList,
  FUN = cbind,
  is.na = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Judging from your last two questions, you could probably benefit from reading `help(lapply)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `replace`

```
dfList1 <- lapply(dfList, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0))
dfList1
#[[1]]
#  apples oranges
#1      1       2
#2      0       4

#[[2]]
#  apples oranges
#1      1       2
#2      0       4

#[[3]]
#  apples oranges
#1      1       2
#2      0       4
```

#### data

```
df2 <- df1
df3 <- df1
dfList1 <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

Comment: @Sathish I have to give a return statement for x